# Dash DatePickerRange with csv file

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, plotly-dash

I am doing graph based on my logged (csv file) outdoor and indoor temperatures with Dash. I am trying to get graph working with the DatePickerRager component. Basically what it should do is to edit the graph to show only temperatures in the range based on selected dates. However I can't figure out how this should be done. What I should write in the update_graph function? This is my code so far:

```
import dash
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
import datetime as dt
import pandas as pd

app = dash.Dash()

iTemperature = "Indoor Temperature"

colors = {
    "graphBackground": "#212529",
    "background": "#000000",
    "text": "#ffffff"
}

app.layout = html.Div(style={"backgroundColor": colors["background"]}, children=[
    html.H1(
        children="Home Temperature",
        style={
            "textAlign": "center",
            "color": colors["text"]
        }
    ),

    html.Div(children="Outdoor and indoor temperatures", style={
        "textAlign": "center",
        "color": colors["text"]
    }),

    html.Div(children="", style={
        "color": colors["background"]
    }),

    dcc.DatePickerRange(
        id="date-picker-range",
        start_date=dt.datetime(2018, 5, 22),
        end_date=dt.datetime.now(),
        min_date_allowed=dt.datetime(2018, 5, 22),
        max_date_allowed=dt.datetime.now(),
        end_date_placeholder_text="Select a date"
    ),

    dcc.Graph(
        id="in-temp-graph",
        figure={
            "data": [
                {"x": df.date, "y": df.temperature, "type": "line", "name": iTemperature}, 
            ],
            "layout": {
                "title": iTemperature,
                "plot_bgcolor": colors["graphBackground"],
                "paper_bgcolor": colors["graphBackground"]
            }
        }
    )

])

@app.callback(
    Output("in-temp-graph", "figure"),
    [Input("date-picker-range", "start_date"),
    Input("date-picker-range", "end_date")]
)
def update_graph(start_date, end_date):
    df = pd.read_csv("iTemps.csv")
    return start_date, end_date


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

Thank you for your help!

SOLUTION:

```
import dash
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import datetime as dt
import pandas_datareader.data as web
import pandas as pd

app = dash.Dash()

iTemperature = "Indoor Temperature"
df = pd.read_csv("iTemps.csv")

colors = {
    "graphBackground": "#212529",
    "background": "#000000",
    "text": "#ffffff"
}

app.layout = html.Div(style={"backgroundColor": colors["background"]}, children=[
    html.H1(
        children="Home Temperature",
        style={
            "textAlign": "center",
            "color": colors["text"]
        }
    ),

    html.Div(children="Outdoor and indoor temperatures", style={
        "textAlign": "center",
        "color": colors["text"]
    }),

    html.Div(children="", style={
        "color": colors["background"]
    }),

    dcc.DatePickerRange(
        id="date-picker-range",
        start_date=dt.datetime(2018, 5, 22),
        end_date=dt.datetime(2018, 8, 13),
        min_date_allowed=dt.datetime(2018, 5, 22),
        max_date_allowed=dt.datetime(2018, 8, 13),
        end_date_placeholder_text="Select a date"
    ),

    dcc.Graph(id="in-temp-graph")

])

@app.callback(
    Output("in-temp-graph", "figure"),
    [Input("date-picker-range", "start_date"),
    Input("date-picker-range", "end_date")]
)
def update_graph(start_date, end_date):

    start_date = pd.to_datetime(start_date)
    end_date = pd.to_datetime(end_date)

    filtered_df = df[df.date.between(
        dt.datetime.strftime(start_date, "%Y-%m-%d"),
        dt.datetime.strftime(end_date, "%Y-%m-%d")
    )]

    trace1 = go.Scatter(
        x = filtered_df.date,
        y = filtered_df.temperature,
        mode = "lines",
        name = iTemperature
    )

    return {
        "data": [trace1],
        "layout": go.Layout(
            title = iTemperature,
            plot_bgcolor = colors["graphBackground"],
            paper_bgcolor = colors["graphBackground"]
        )
    }

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing to keep in mind when writing your callback is exactly where it's outputting to: in this case you're building a callback whose output is the "figure" object of the dcc.Graph element; that is to say, whatever you enter in the output's return should *completely define* that component.

With that in mind, you first want to reduce your dcc.Graph element to simply the following within app.layout:

```
dcc.Graph(id="in-temp-graph")
```

And perform the entirety of the construction work of the figure object within the callback (this has the added benefit of making the layout section easier to read - believe me, this is something you'll be glad of as you start working on more complex dashboards).

You'll also want to import your csv file far earlier in the process - before you even begin your app.layout section; you want to import your data once, not every time the user changes the date ranges!

As for the construction of the callback, following the design your example suggested something like this should work:

```
@app.callback(
    Output("in-temp-graph", "figure"),
    [Input("date-picker-range", "start_date"),
    Input("date-picker-range", "end_date")]
)
def update_graph(start_date, end_date):

    # first, filter your dataset to the relevant selection
    filtered_df = df[df.date.between(
        dt.datetime.strptime(start_date,'%Y-%m-%d'),
        dt.datetime.strptime(end_date,'%Y-%m-%d'))]

    # then build the trace you'll be using based on this dataset
    trace1 = go.Scatter(
        x = filtered_df.date, 
        y = filtered_df.temperature,
        mode = 'lines',
        name: iTemperature)

    # finally, output your figure object
    return {
        'data': [trace1],
        'layout': go.Layout(
            title = iTemperature,
            plot_bgcolor = colors["graphBackground"],
            paper_bgcolor = colors["graphBackground"])
```

A major caveat here - I am making assumptions about the nature of your extract, and the transformation work you'll carry out on it: specifically, I'm reformatting the strings that date-picker-range outputs into a datetime format  (e.g. `dt.datetime.strptime(start_date,'%Y-%m-%d')`), on the assumption that you will have converted your extract's "date" column into a datetime.

If, however, you convert said column into a pure *date* instead, you'll need to append the `.date()` instruction to the above (e.g. `dt.datetime.strptime(start_date,'%Y-%m-%d').date()`), as you can't compare a datetime to a date. This will also go for the default values for your date-picker-range, as they too are currently formatted as datetimes.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It clarified things a bit. However now I'm getting following error message when I'm running the app `TypeError: unorderable types: str() >= datetime.date()`. My csv file looks like this:
`date,temperature
2018-05-22 19:00:02,23.9
2018-05-22 20:00:03,24.6` and so on.

Comment: I edited how code looks now to the original question

Comment: Got it now working. I put the solution to the original question. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Glad to have been of use! Apologies for not replying sooner - it's been a bank holiday here, and I spent it as far away from computers as possible.
You correctly identified the issue - your date column was formatted as a string, whereas the date picker returns a datetime, and the two couldn't be directly compared. Converting the datetimes to strings is the opposite approach to the one I would opt for, but given the format of your date (YYYY-MM-DD) should work without issue, as even string ordering should work as desired. Just be careful not to switch to DD-MM-YYYY or any other date layout!